# Non-public API usage: Apps are not permitted to access the UDID and must not use the uniqueIdentifier method of UIDevice

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

When validating my app in **Xcode 6.3** , I am getting following error :

[image: **Non-public API usage: Apps are not permitted to access the UDID and must not use the uniqueIdentifier method of UIDevice. Please update your apps and servers to associate users with the Vendor or Advertising identifiers introduced in iOS 6.**]

There are no third party frameworks, such as **AdMob**, Google **Analytics**, **Flurry**, or **Facebook**, used in the app. Only inbuilt frameworks are used. Also, the frameworks that are used in the app are up to date.

I have tried the following command in the terminal to find the class that uses the **UDID**;

> find . | grep -v .svn  | grep ".a" | grep -v ".app" | xargs grep
>   uniqueIdentifier

but there is no listing of such files.

I have also searched for `**[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]**` in my code, but it is not used anywhere.

So what should i do to solve this?

Comment: That `find` won't work as it looks broken to me.  What's wrong with `find . -name \*.m -exec grep -l uniqueIdentifier {} \;`?

Comment: @trojanfoe   I tried it. It wouldn't work. It does not display anything.

Comment: I suggest you do what's explained in the third error message, which seems pretty clear that their error log can be unreliable and that you should complain :l

Answer (score 0):

Your error message from Xcode does not match the error message you're asking about. Expand the window at look for the selectors mentioned in the second bullet. I see "addObserver:" in the text, but we can't read the rest.

The message also points you to how to contact Apple if you believe it is in error. Have you contacted them?